# Can't get the value from view model in the cell

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, collectionview

I'm working on weather tracker and want to display some data in my ViewController, but I don't understand why some value from my view model is on closure, but not displayed in my collection view

**JSON**

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0,
    "cnt": 3,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1638370800,
            "main": {
                "temp": 282.21,
                "feels_like": 279.54,
                "temp_min": 281.53,
                "temp_max": 282.21,
                "pressure": 998,
                "sea_level": 998,
                "grnd_level": 995,
                "humidity": 71,
                "temp_kf": 0.68
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10d"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 79
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5.05,
                "deg": 288,
                "gust": 10.52
            },
            "visibility": 10000,
            "pop": 0.48,
            "rain": {
                "3h": 0.21
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "d"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2021-12-01 15:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1638381600,
            "main": {
                "temp": 280.71,
                "feels_like": 277.76,
                "temp_min": 279.79,
                "temp_max": 280.71,
                "pressure": 1000,
                "sea_level": 1000,
                "grnd_level": 998,
                "humidity": 76,
                "temp_kf": 0.92
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 500,
                    "main": "Rain",
                    "description": "light rain",
                    "icon": "10n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 87
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 4.84,
                "deg": 20,
                "gust": 10.28
            },
            "visibility": 10000,
            "pop": 0.88,
            "rain": {
                "3h": 1.15
            },
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2021-12-01 18:00:00"
        },
        {
            "dt": 1638392400,
            "main": {
                "temp": 278.21,
                "feels_like": 274.28,
                "temp_min": 278.21,
                "temp_max": 278.21,
                "pressure": 1005,
                "sea_level": 1005,
                "grnd_level": 1002,
                "humidity": 72,
                "temp_kf": 0
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "id": 803,
                    "main": "Clouds",
                    "description": "broken clouds",
                    "icon": "04n"
                }
            ],
            "clouds": {
                "all": 73
            },
            "wind": {
                "speed": 5.62,
                "deg": 345,
                "gust": 10.72
            },
            "visibility": 10000,
            "pop": 0.39,
            "sys": {
                "pod": "n"
            },
            "dt_txt": "2021-12-01 21:00:00"
        }
    ],
    "city": {
        "id": 2643743,
        "name": "London",
        "coord": {
            "lat": 51.5085,
            "lon": -0.1257
        },
        "country": "GB",
        "population": 1000000,
        "timezone": 0,
        "sunrise": 1638344651,
        "sunset": 1638374122
    }
}
```

**My struct**

```
struct TwentyFourHoursCitiesWeather: Decodable {
    let cod: String
    let message, cnt: Int
    let list: [List]
    let city: City
}

// MARK: - City
struct City: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let coord: Coord
    let country: String
    let population, timezone, sunrise, sunset: Int
}

// MARK: - Coord
struct Coord: Decodable {
    let lat, lon: Double
}

// MARK: - List
struct List: Decodable {
    let dt: Int
    let main: TwentyFourHoursMain
    let weather: [TwentyFourHoursWeather]
    let clouds: TwentyFourHoursClouds
    let wind: TwentyFourHoursWind
    let visibility: Int
    let pop: Double
    let rain: Rain?
    let sys: TwentyFourHoursSys
    let dtTxt: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case dt, main, weather, clouds, wind, visibility, pop, rain, sys
        case dtTxt = "dt_txt"
    }
}

// MARK: - Clouds
struct TwentyFourHoursClouds: Decodable {
    let all: Int
}

// MARK: - Main
struct TwentyFourHoursMain: Decodable {
    let temp, feelsLike, tempMin, tempMax: Double
    let pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity: Int
    let tempKf: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case temp
        case feelsLike = "feels_like"
        case tempMin = "temp_min"
        case tempMax = "temp_max"
        case pressure
        case seaLevel = "sea_level"
        case grndLevel = "grnd_level"
        case humidity
        case tempKf = "temp_kf"
    }
}

// MARK: - Rain
struct Rain: Decodable {
    let the3H: Double

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case the3H = "3h"
    }
}

// MARK: - Sys
struct TwentyFourHoursSys: Decodable {
    let pod: String
}

// MARK: - Weather
struct TwentyFourHoursWeather: Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let main, weatherDescription, icon: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, main
        case weatherDescription = "description"
        case icon
    }
}

// MARK: - Wind
struct TwentyFourHoursWind: Decodable {
    let speed: Double
    let deg: Int
    let gust: Double
}
```

**My WeatherService, when I get data:**

```
protocol ITwentyFourHoursWeatherService {
    
    func getCitiesWeather(completion: @escaping (Result<TwentyFourHoursCitiesWeather, Error>) -> Void)
}

enum TwentyFourHoursWeatherServiceError: Error {
    case badUrl
}

private extension String {
    static let url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London&cnt=3&appid=KEY"
}
    
final class TwentyFourHoursWeatherService: ITwentyFourHoursWeatherService {

    func getCitiesWeather(completion: @escaping (Result<TwentyFourHoursCitiesWeather, Error>) -> Void) {
        guard let url = URL(string: .url) else {
            return completion(.failure(TwentyFourHoursWeatherServiceError.badUrl))
        }

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

            do {
                let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(TwentyFourHoursCitiesWeather.self, from: data)
                completion(.success(result))
                print("24 weatherService: \(result.list[0].main.temp)") <--I get data here
            } catch {
                print("failed to convert \(error)")
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }

}
```

**My ViewModel:**

class TwentyFourHoursViewModel {

```
// MARK: -Properties
let twentyFourHoursWeatherService: ITwentyFourHoursWeatherService

var twentyFourHoursWeather: TwentyFourHoursMainScreenWeatherModel?

init(twentyFourHoursWeatherService: ITwentyFourHoursWeatherService) {
    self.twentyFourHoursWeatherService = twentyFourHoursWeatherService
}

func twentyFourHoursViewDidLoad() {
    
    twentyFourHoursWeatherService.getCitiesWeather { [weak self] result in
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let result):
            self?.twentyFourHoursWeather = .init(
                twentyFourHoursTime: result.list[2].dtTxt ,
                twentyFourHoursIcon: "sunset",
                twentyFourHoursTemp: result.list[1].main.temp
            )
            self?.twentyFourHoursWeatherDidChange?()
            print("In twentyFourHoursViewModel: \(result.list[0].main.temp)") <-- Get data here
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

var twentyFourHoursWeatherDidChange: (() -> Void)?
```

**My ViewController:**

```
class MainScrenenViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let twentyFourHoursViewModel: TwentyFourHoursViewModel
    
    //CollectionView 
    var todayCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let todayCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        todayCollectionView.register(TwentyFourHoursCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "todayCell")
        todayCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        todayCollectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        return todayCollectionView
    }()
    
    //MARK: - Initialization
    
    init(twentyFourHoursViewModel: TwentyFourHoursViewModel) {
        self.twentyFourHoursViewModel = twentyFourHoursViewModel
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        
        view.addSubview(todayCollectionView)
        
        todayCollectionView.dataSource = self
        todayCollectionView.delegate = self
        
        setupConstraints()
        
        twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursWeatherDidChange = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                print("Значение из замыкания: \(self.twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursWeather?.twentyFourHoursTemp)") <--And I get data here
            }
        }
        
        twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursViewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
//MARK: - Collection

extension MainScrenenViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
            return 3
    
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        
            let cellTwo = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "todayCell", for: indexPath) as! TwentyFourHoursCollectionViewCell
        
            if let temp: String? = String(twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursWeather?.twentyFourHoursTemp ?? 1.1) {
                cellTwo.mainTemperatureLabel.text = temp
                print("Значение в ячейке: \(temp)") <-- There is nil here
            }
 
        return cellTwo
}
```

**Collection View Cell**

```
class TwentyFourHoursCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    var mainTemperatureLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "Rubik-Medium", size: 16)
        label.textColor = .black
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        contentView.addSubview(mainTemperatureLabel)
        
        //self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        
        let constraints = [
            
            mainTemperatureLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor),
            mainTemperatureLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerXAnchor),
            mainTemperatureLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
            mainTemperatureLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
    }
    
    required init?( coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBmqg.png)

Comment: You are assigning `result.list[1].main.temp` to `temp` but everywhere else you use index 0

Comment: Change this `if let temp: String? =` to `if let temp: String =` or even `if let temp =`. It doesn't make much sense for an if let to return an optional. You want an actual value at this point. Also try breaking that long optional chain down to discrete intermediate values and see what is going on. Set a breakpoint. Use the very powerful Xcode debugger to step through your code. Note that you would expect to get `nil` when you collection view first displays and then a value when it is reloaded

Comment: @Paulw11 I get en error when write `if let temp =` **Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'**

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry, I don't understand this comment: **You are assigning result.list[1].main.temp to temp but everywhere else you use index 0**

Comment: You say `twentyFourHoursTemp: result.list[1].main.temp` in your `.success` case but in your logs you use `list[0]`

Comment: And the error message about the conditional binding means you haven't sufficiently unwrapped your optionals. As I said, break that complex statement down into a series of intermediate steps so that you can see exactly what is `nil`.  You have a nil coalescing operator inside the `String` initialiser so you shouldn't get `nil` there. It seems likely that your string initialiser itself is returning `nil`.

Comment: @Paulw11 I assign value of `result.list[1].main.temp` to `twentyFourHoursTemp`and I can get this value in my View Controller, but in the cell in this View Controller I can't get this value. The value is 1.1 `if let temp: String? = String(twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursWeather?.twentyFourHoursTemp ?? 1.1)`

Comment: @Paulw11 And I get this, when activate breakpoint: `Task <403FDAEE-76C3-4081-8AA9-764DED31A0C8>.<1> finished with error [-1001] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSUnderlyingError=0x600002280e70 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <403FDAEE-76C3-4081-8AA9-764DED31A0C8>.<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <403FDAEE-76C3-4081-8AA9-764DED31A0C8>.<1>`

Comment: If you set a breakpoint it stops all processing, including  any background network operations. If you wait too long before resuming you will get a timeout. As I said, I would expect that code to be called twice. Once before you have the data and then when you reload the view. The first time you hit the breakpoint quickly hit the continue button and wait for the second hit.

Answer (score 1):

`if let temp: String? = String(twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursWeather?.twentyFourHoursTemp ?? 1.1)` is not correct otherwise you should at least have 1.1 as temp.

instead try to unwrap the optional value and use it from there:

```
if let weather = twentyFourHoursViewModel.twentyFourHoursWeather {
    cellTwo.mainTemperatureLabel.text = String(weather.twentyFourHoursTemp)
    print("Значение в ячейке: \(weather.twentyFourHoursTemp)")
 }
```

You are also initializing a mixed TwentyFourHoursWeather object with the result:

```
self?.twentyFourHoursWeather = .init(                                                  
                twentyFourHoursTime: result.list[2].dtTxt ,
                twentyFourHoursIcon: "sunset",
                twentyFourHoursTemp: result.list[1].main.temp
            )
```

That is taking time from the third list object, hard coding the icon, and taking temp from the second list object. The rest of your code seems to indicate that you would want to use the first object for each until there is a change. ie `result.list[0].dtTxt` , etc

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I get `No exact matches in call to initializer` in this code: `cellTwo.mainTemperatureLabel.text = String(weather.twentyFourHoursTemp)`